# I keep receiving this error when trying to run my Shiny app: "Warning: Error in readChar: cannot open the connection [No stack trace available]"

Tags: r, shiny

The following is my R code for the Shiny app that I am trying to run. Running the script will build the app but when I feed the app the excel spreadsheet to generate a report via the mother script, I receive the error message:

**Warning: Error in readChar: cannot open the connection
[No stack trace available]**

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = "report.pdf",
      content = function(file) {
        # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
        # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
        # can happen when deployed).
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "Mother_script.Rmd")
        file.copy("Mother_script.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        
        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(n = input$file1)
        
        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        # from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file, 
                          params = params, 
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

I am not sure where the disconnect is. If anyone can point out an error in my script that could be causing this error, I would greatly appreciate!

Comment: Can you provide a "Mother_script.Rmd" or other sample file that can be used for testing?

Comment: Hi MrFlick, the Mother script is
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
dataset<-params$n
```